# Sharing a Cocoa Framework between apps (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode

I have created a dynamic framework for one of my apps as I was using a lot of the same code for the main app and the extensions. This works well and has reduced the amount of duplicate code in the project.

I am now looking at creating a second app and it would save me a huge amount of time if I could use the framework from the first app.

How would I go about doing this?

My initial thought is to break the framework out into it's own project and include that project in the app projects by using a workspace.

Another thought was to have both apps in the same project, but as different targets.

I also use git, so it would be beneficial to have the framework separate from the apps.

Comment: If you're using git then you can always create a separate project for your framework and submodule it for each app. This is what we used to do and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks @GuyKogus I'll have a look at git submodules. Presumably it will show up in Xcode as a nested project?

Comment: Yes indeed. In Xcode you have the framework project as a dependency of the app project. Xcode doesn't really care about how you set up the SCM, it will automatically recognise which files belong to which repository. You just need to tell Xcode in the 'Build Phases' section that the framework is a 'Target Dependency' and you will need to include the static library (.a file) built by the framework in the 'Link Binary With Libraries' section.

Comment: have you tried out to put the shared code into a Cocoa Touch Framework? I ran into linking errors with that as described in my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212761/how-to-use-cocoa-touch-frameworks-in-an-app-project